# How to get dropdown/radio button text from Request.form

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
public void SaveData(int taskAssignmentId, int formId, int userId,     NameValueCollection col)
{
  foreach (string key in col.Keys)
  {
    string value = col[key]; //Gets Value
  }
}
```

The variable "value" gets value of the dropdown/radio button. Any idea how to retrieve the dropdown/radio button text.

FYI: Request.Form is passed as the parameter col ( type NameValueCollection)

Comment: where do you have this `SaveData()` method defined? is it in a separate class? or in a separate page?

Comment: SaveData() method is in a separate class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this

```
foreach (string key in col.AllKeys) { string value = key; }
```

Comment: That will still get you the name. I need the text (inner HTML )

Comment: How are you adding the controls to the NameValueCollection? The .Add method lets you define the Name and Value, which if you were to assign the controls text to the Name, col.AllKeys would work.

Comment: My apologies, you did mention that in your question. To the best of my knowledge, you can't get the text value directly from Request.Form. You could do use the FindControl and cast that a radio button ((RadioButton)this.FindControl(key)).Text if you are running this method from the same page. Also, the Request.Form will only bring back radio buttons that are checked, though it might be worth mentioning that.